# I want to make the surroundings glow with a rim light

Tags: rigging, shader-nodes

(3) With Unity-based software, when backlighting a character, I want to make the surroundings glow with a rim light.

Example:
[image: Rim]

I want to set the rim light to the clothes and display the rim light on something that uses the Unity engine, such as the VRMLive viewer. is.

The part made with Vroid reacted when I set RImcolor in the Vroid shader, but (human part)
The clothes look different.
I tried setting it using MN toonshade node, but it didn't work.[image]

Comment: Thanks, I do it but it couldn't.
I add more information at Question.

And I couldn't do this.
>>>you will need to "bake" the emission lighting using an Irradiance Volume in order for the light to affect the surroundings.

Answer (score 2):

I would combine your existing material with an *Emission Shader*, using a *Fresnel* as a *Mix Factor* to "force" the emission to the rim. You can also experiment with the *Fresnel* and *Facing* outputs of a *Layer Weight* node, however, I think a simple *Fresnel* should suffice.

You can include a *ColorRamp* to gain better control of the "tightness" of the rim lighting. You may have to set the emission strength rather high. Don't forget to turn on Bloom if you're using EEVEE (highlighted right side).

If you are using EEVEE, you will need to "bake" the emission lighting using an *Irradiance Volume* in order for the light to affect the surroundings. If you're using Cycles, you will have to render the scene first, then use a glare node in the Compositor to get the "glow".

[image: FresnelEmit]

[image]

I edited it after watching the answer.
It looks good in Blender, though, in Unity it became white.
Maybe the texture disappeared.

Img4 is another dater that succeeds.
I added a new texture and connect the main texture.
It can use rim light upper the texture in Unity software.

The data structure is not the same structure.

But I don't know how to do the same things in this file.

I watched this setting at Unity game software(VRM Live viewer)
The setting becomes emission so the body becomes white.
I control emission setting decrease so texture appears.
It doesn't become rim light setting.

[image]

[image]